# Select average of product rate using date backtracking

Tags: sql-server, backtracking

I'm querying monthly average rate of all products, average of all Friday rates of that month. My table and data script is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product_Entry](
    [ProductCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [RateDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050101', CAST(56 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-05' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050102', CAST(60 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-05' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050103', CAST(65 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-04' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050101', CAST(50 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-12' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050102', CAST(64 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-11' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050103', CAST(70 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-12' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050101', CAST(55 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-15' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050102', CAST(50 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-16' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Product_Entry] ([ProductCode], [Rate], [RateDate]) VALUES (N'050103', CAST(68 AS Decimal(18, 0)), CAST(N'2019-04-17' AS Date))
GO
```

So I make a function which take Month & Year and returns all fridays

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetallFridaysinMonth] (  
 @month VARCHAR(2) = NULL  
 ,@year VARCHAR(5) = NULL  
 )  
AS  
BEGIN  
 SELECT Fridays = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, '' + @year + '-' + @month + '-' + '01'), n.num)  
 INTO #t  
 FROM (  
  SELECT TOP 366 num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (  
    ORDER BY a.NAME  
    ) - 1  
  FROM dbo.syscolumns a  
   ,dbo.syscolumns b  
  ) n  
 WHERE DATENAME(weekday, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, '' + @year + '-' + @month + '-' + '01'), n.num)) = 'Friday'  

 SELECT Fridays  
 FROM #t  
 WHERE datepart(month, Fridays) = @month  

 DROP TABLE #t  
END
```

Then use this function to query averages

```
BEGIN  
  CREATE TABLE #t121 (Fridays DATETIME,id INT IDENTITY(1, 1));  

  INSERT INTO #t121 (Fridays)  
  EXEC dbo.GetallFridaysinMonth @month,@year;  

   SELECT ProductCode  
    ,convert(DECIMAL(18), avg(Rate)) AS AverageRate  
   FROM dbo.product_entry  
   WHERE RateDate IN (  
     SELECT Fridays  
     FROM #t121  
     )  
   GROUP BY ProductCode  
  DROP TABLE #t121  
END
```

This works very well until my client modify requirement and say if there is no rate in Friday then check in Thursday, if not in Thursday then check in Wednesday means backtrack to Saturday to find that Weeks Rate.

Now if there is only 2 or 3 products then I can use Case condition but don't know how to backtrack for all products which are over 250.

My expected result of demo data is

```
ProductCode   AverageRate
-------------------------
050101      54
050102      58
050103      68
```

After round off.

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you replace the image of your data with a consumable format please. We can't make use of your image so it isn't helpful. Instead provide us with DDL and DML so that we can then use the SQL you have to see where it's not working. You're far less likely to get an answer by forcing the volunteers to transcribe your image. Also show us the results you're expecting from that sample data (again, preferably not as an image, however, formatted `text` is fine as we don't need to consume it in the same way). Thanks.

Comment: @Larnu Thank. Add script for demo data.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to update the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These could be the minimum changes to achieve the new requirements:

```
begin
    create table #t121 (Fridays datetime);

    insert into #t121 (Fridays)
    exec dbo.GetallFridaysinMonth @month, @year;

    with AVGDaily as (
        select ProductCode, RateDate, AVG(Rate) as AVGDay
        from dbo.Product_Entry
        where month(RateDate)=@month and year(RateDate)=@year
        group by ProductCode, RateDate
    )
    select ProductCode
        ,  convert(decimal(18), AVG(AVGRate)) as AverageRate
    from (
        select distinct t.Fridays, AVGDaily.ProductCode, 
        AVGRate=(
            select top (1) AVGDay
            from AVGDaily i2
            where ProductCode = AVGDaily.ProductCode
                and i2.RateDate between
                    DATEADD(DD, -6, t.Fridays) and t.Fridays
            order by RateDate desc)
        from AVGDaily, #t121 as t) g
    group by ProductCode
    drop table #t121
end
```

and maybe the proc could be improved:

```
CREATE Proc GetallFridaysinMonth(@month varchar(2), @year varchar(4), @dw tinyint=5) as 
declare @dateStart datetime, @maxDDinMM tinyint
select @dateStart = cast(right('20'+@year,4)+right('0'+@month,2)+'01' as datetime)
    ,  @maxDDinMM = DATEDIFF(DD, @dateStart, DATEADD(MM, 1, @dateStart)) - 1;
with ADD_cte as (
    select 0 as AddDays
    union all
    select AddDays + 1 from ADD_cte where AddDays < @maxDDinMM
)
select DATEADD(DD, AddDays, @dateStart) as SalesDay
from ADD_cte
where (DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DD, AddDays, @dateStart)) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 = @dw
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CTEs and Row_Number() I partitioned your data by Product Code and then the Week of the Month sorted by the Day of the Week descending.  (I set the query to retrieve the current year only).  Then, by only looking at row 1, it will average by Product Code for the latest day of each week.

```
;With cte1 As
(
Select 
    *,
    Case When DatePart(dw,RateDate) = 7 Then 0 Else DatePart(dw,RateDate) End  As dowN, --Day of week Number (Make Saturday = 0 instead of 7)
    Datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, RateDate)/7 * 7)/7 + 1 As wom  --Week of Month Number
From Product_Entry
Where Year(RateDate) = Year(GetDate())  --Current Year Only
), cte2 As
(
Select 
      Row_Number() Over (Partition By ProductCode, wom Order By dowN Desc) As rn,
      * 
From cte1
)
Select ProductCode, Cast(Round(AVG(Rate),0) As Int) As AverageRate From cte2
Where rn = 1     
Group By ProductCode
```

Comment: @Xabi Thanks for your answers. Both solutions working for me but I want to know which is better in performance for over a million records.